# How to delete that directory?

Tags: permissions, directory, rm

I have a directory, that I cannot delete with `rmdir`. I get always a `permission denied` error. But when list the directory (with `ls -l`) I get this:

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 user user 4096 Aug 28 09:34 directory
```

`stat` gives me that:

```
  File: `directory/'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 16         IO Block: 32768  directory
Device: 12h/18d Inode: 102368771   Links: 2
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/  user)   Gid: ( 1000/  user)
Access: 2015-08-31 03:00:20.630000002 +0200
Modify: 2015-08-28 09:34:16.772930001 +0200
Change: 2015-08-31 12:25:04.920000000 +0200
```

So how delete that directory.

Comment: What are the permissions of its parent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are trying to delete a directory `foo/bar/`, the permissions of `bar` isn't the relevant factor.  Removing the name `bar` from directory `foo` is a modification of `foo`.  So you need write permissions on `foo`.

In your case, check the current directory's permissions with `ls -ld .`

You might find [this answer to "why is rm allowed to delete a file under ownership of a different user?"](/a/226565/112566) enlightening.

Answer (score 2):

Inside that `dir` must be a file without the needed permissions. Try changing the owner `recursively` to all the `dir` and then remove it.

```
$ sudo chown -R user:user dir/
$ rm -rf dir/
```

From `man rm`

```
-r, -R, --recursive
  remove directories and their contents recursively
-f, --force
          ignore nonexistent files, never prompt
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that the "immutable bit" is set on this directory. You can check it with `ls -d <directory>`. Permissions set with `chattr` won't show up on the `stat` output:

```
stephan@x230 ~ % stat testdir
  File: ‘testdir’
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 13713629    Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/ stephan)   Gid: ( 1000/ stephan)
Access: 2015-08-31 14:05:49.957299346 +0200
Modify: 2015-08-31 14:05:25.657267292 +0200
Change: 2015-08-31 14:05:42.685289494 +0200
 Birth: -


stephan@x230 ~ % lsattr -d testdir
----i--------e-- testdir`
```

You have to be root to remove the immutable bit:
`chattr -i testdir`